# Korean or Chinese manhua about a girl who reincarnated into a noble family

Tags: story-identification, isekai

The previous owner of her current body was a mean and ill tempered girl. The story revolves around how she wants to fulfil the previous body owner's wish to become the queen, to do that she has to become rivals with the prince's lover. Sorry I didn't give enough information I don't actually remember much But I remember that the mc' body's previous owner was a mean girl and she used to bully the prince's lover because she liked the prince. Long story short after mc got reincarnated she tried to become friends with the girl the previous body owner used to bully  but discovered later that the prince's lover wasn't actually a naive girl but a calculative cunning one. Mc didn't really like the prince (at least when I stopped reading) and became FRIENDS with his half brother the fifth prince. To ruin the mc's image, the prince's lover sent a spy that told her that the relationship between the fifth prince and mc was suspicious and so prince's lover tried shaming her in front of everyone but failed (because crown  prince took action) . Sorry I know I'm might not be giving enough information but that's all I can remember. 
Ps. I don't remember the last time I read it but it might have been 3 months ago or so

Comment: Can you remember when you read this? How old it would be? What happens i.e. does she end up becoming queen? Do things all pan out as expected? etc. You can [edit] your question to add in any other detail.

Comment: Do you remember if the main character was engaged to the prince and there was someone else who the prince would fall in love with?  When you say the prince's lover, do you mean his fiance, or merely that he is interested in someone who is not the main character?

Comment: If it is chinese manhua, then there will be a lot of it. Mostly all girl(doctor, assassin, ...) reincarnated in a noble family.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out the name of the manhua I was searching for. It's called "the justice of a villainous woman". I'm so happy I found it after so long~ シ thank you guys for trying to help‍♀️[image]

Comment: You can self-accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].